# retain comments post XSLT transform

Tags: xml, xslt, comments

This seems like an easy one, but one that I haven't come across before.

I need to retain the comments in an XML file to the output XML after applying an XSLT.

Does anyone know how/if this is possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XSL you can reference comments in your source XML similar to other elements, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

If it should appear in your transformed XML as comment as well you can do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I had this in the XSLT, but I wasn't getting any output. I found that the XSLT had a template match="comment()" already and was set to suppress them.

Comment: The standard identity transform has a template that matches `node()|@*`. A comment is one of the things that `node()` matches.