# Keeping comments when transforming XML with XSLT

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to keep comments in an XML when applying an XSLT to it?

Example (source):

```
<rootNode>
  <!-- My comment --><childElement>5</childElement>
</rootNode>
```

The sample result after the transformation shall be:

```
<newRoot>
  <!-- My comment --><newChildElement>5</newChildElement>
</newRoot>
```

How would you write the stylesheet?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407636/retain-comments-post-xslt-transform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not proper XML comment syntax in your sample but you can keep all nodes with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then you add templates for the nodes to be transformed

```
<xsl:template match="childElement">
  <newChildElement>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </newChildElement>
</xsl:template>
```

My suggestions assumes the sample as

```
<rootNode>
  <!-- My comment--><childElement>5</childElement>
</rootNode>
```

and the result as

```
<rootNode>
  <!-- My comment--><newChildElement>5</newChildElement>
</rootNode>
```

If the `childElement` is inside the comment then it is more difficult.

Comment: You are right. The XML comment was not correct. I edited my question.

Comment: @Robert, my suggestion does work fine for that type of input, the first template copies all types of nodes level by level and the second template kicks in for the element you want to transform. Comment nodes are kept by the first template, like other nodes you don't want to change.

Comment: This is a far better solution than `<xsl:template match="comment()">`.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straightforward, if I understand the question correctly:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```